# Boiler pilot not lighting up

Tags: water, gas, boiler

[image: flame]

I was unable to get pilot lit by pressing button and using lighter. So I tried my torch on the thermocoupler and turned the gas knob on and it came on, hence the picture. Yet the pilot light still is not on. So I don't think it's a bad thermocoupler but maybe a bad gas line to the pilot light.

Anyone knowledgeable about this?

Comment: Sounds reasonable. I have some ventless gas logs that if I leave off completely off for a season or two will get clogged and with spiderwebs and sand from the old masonry.  Cleaning the pilot by blowing and brushing from the open side without any disassembly has fixed it for me.

Comment: Yes, what @DaveX said.  I fixed a friend's that way...a simple clean-out of the pilot tubing was all that was required.

Comment: Thanks finally got around to getting a bit for my sure compressor to blow it out, and it works now

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Clean out the open end of the pilot light to make sure there is no debris interfering with the flow.

I have some ventless gas logs that if I leave off completely off for a season or two will get clogged and with spiderwebs and sand from the old masonry. Cleaning the pilot by blowing and brushing from the open side without any disassembly has fixed it for me.

(reposted from comment)